# iPhone Is there a way to get a nsdate from a NSDateComponents

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to figure out how to create a `NSDate` that is set to the end of the year. ie 2013,
I found a method that you can get the time since 1970 by adding the amount of seconds.  I don't see this working because cal the seconds would have to take in leap years.

I found the following code to set a `NSDateComponents` to the end of the year.

```
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setYear:2012];
    [comps setMonth:12];
    [comps setDay:11];

    [comps setHour:0];
    [comps setMinute:0];
    [comps setSecond:0];
```

is there a way to get a `NSDate` from this?
What I'm trying to do is get the amount of time until the end of the year by using

```
NSDateComponents *timeDifference = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
                                        components:  NSMonthCalendarUnit| NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit  fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:comps options:0];
```

which needs a `NSDate` for the end date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Use

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```

You can change the calender identifier as per your requirement.

Please refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Heres some code that may point you in the right direction.

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:2012];
[comps setMonth:12];
[comps setDay:11];

[comps setHour:0];
[comps setMinute:0];
[comps setSecond:0];

NSDate *myDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
```