# Getting an NSDateComponents instance from an NSDate (Or DateTime) in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I need to get a fully defined [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDateComponents) instance (i.e. with calender, timezone, and the actual date values etc set) to be used as the [StartDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKReminderClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKReminder/startDateComponents) and [DueDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKReminderClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKReminder/dueDateComponents) values of an [EKReminder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKReminderClassRef/Reference/Reference.html).

There are plenty of [answers here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210367/505457) explaining how to do it from a calendar instance in obj-c. And open source projects [doing the same thing](https://github.com/kevinbirch/sched/blob/master/src/EventKitController.m#L96-L100).

However I can't seem to work out how to do the same thing in MT. The [NSCalendar](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=T:MonoTouch.Foundation.NSCalendar/*) class doesn't expose any method related to the `components:fromDate:` selector.

How have people dealt with DateTime/NSDate -> NSDateComponents in MT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These API are effectively missing from MonoTouch - but I've now added them so you'll will find them in a future release.

In the meantime you can call `components:fromDate:` manually:

```
var calendar = new NSCalendar (NSCalendarType.Gregorian);
var date = (NSDate) DateTime.Now;
var ptr = Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend_UInt32_IntPtr (calendar.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("components:fromDate:"), (uint) (NSCalendarUnit.Year | NSCalendarUnit.Month), date.Handle);
var comps = new NSDateComponents (ptr);

Console.WriteLine (comps.Year);
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up manually constructing a `NSDateComponents` and setting the Calendar, Timezone, and all the Date/Time integer properties. Calendar and Timezone came from the static getters returning the respective defaults. I think its fine, I'm just concerned I'm missing some edge case, especially related to why the obj-c method takes those NSCalendarUnit enums, as my approach is missing that information and so cannot be doing the exact same thing. Can you see any probs with this approach rather than using the manual interop approach you posted?

Comment: The NSCalendarUnit values are just to specify exactly which values of the date you want into the date components. In my example you'd get an NSDateComponents with year and month (but not day/hour/minute/second/etc). If your code works when you test it there should be no problem (just make sure you test in different timezones).